# Price in Cart is not correct Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, cart, configurable-product

Today I've run into a new problem and can´t find a solution.
I've added some simple products and configurable products via MagMI. Everything is fine. Products are shown in the front-end as I want it. But following happens:

simple product 1 has a price of 49€, simple product 2 has a price of 90€.

Both are part of the same configurable product which has a price of 49€. Now, in cart, the single-price of both simples is 49€. (If I print out `$_item->getSku()` I get the right skus of the simple products, so I think, the products in cart are the correct ones)

How can I fix this?

It would be also helpful if someone could tell me where the subtotal is built exactly - I can't find this.

I would be thankful for all help or hints.

Comment: Are the simple products visible individually?  If they are not, then the price shown will be the price of the configurable product.  The pricing variations on the associated single products are managed in the Associated Products tab of the configurable item.  Pricing is managed here as a plus/minus relative to the price of the main configurable.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the mistake. The plus/minus was empty. But the simple products are not visible too. But with the plus/minus value it works as I want it. Tanks!

Comment: No problem :)  I'll add it as an answer then as it's answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the simple products are not visible individually then the price shown will be the price of the configurable product. The pricing variations on the associated single products are managed in the Associated Products tab of the configurable item.

Pricing is managed here as a plus/minus relative to the price of the main configurable.