# Magento: price on cart is from configurable product, not from simple-product

Tags: magento, cart, configurable-product

I had a similar problem last time, but the solution just helps with my test-product, whre I can add price +/- in my configurable product. [Price in Cart is not correct Magento 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259953/price-in-cart-is-not-correct-magento-1-8)

Is it possible to take the price of the simple product, without adding some prices +/- at the configurable one?

On cart I get the SKU of the simple-product, but with $_item->getPrice() I only get the Price of the configurable product.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the sku of the item to load the simple product, for example:

```
$_productSku = $_item->getSku();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_productId = $_product->getIdBySku($_productSku);
$_product->load($_productId);
```

then use

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

Regards
Hans

Comment: Very nice, Thanks for the quick answer. Could you laos advise me, how to edit total price on the end of the page (where the total price of all products is shown). I need to take the simple-products prices to generated the total price

Comment: What you are trying to do is to hack the magento price calculation. If you are not 100% sure what you're doing, you should consider using the Magento default way and set the +/- prices in the configurable products.

Comment: Thats the problem. It is not possible to set +/- price. Little example off the prducts: products are colors, attributes a has options "outside, inside, wood", attribute b has options "1liter, 2.5liter, 5liter" - so there is the product blue: outside-1l costs 49€, outside-2.5l costs 90€, inside-1l costs 39€, inside-2.5l costs 77€, wood-1l costs 45€, wood-2.5l costs 87€. So with this prices I think it is not possible to take +/- prices, isn`t it?

Comment: I think you need to look into the tax helper calls, for example:

$_priceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), true, $shippingAddress, $billingAddress, null, $storeId);

Comment: So...I can display the prices in cart and in the checkout review. But if I place the order, the prices are not correct in the backend and at the payment. So I think, I really have to change the magento calculation...but how...does anyone have experience with that or can show me a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution is:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());
$_product->getPrice();
```